# Extract data from Array into it's own array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping, reduce

I have the following data in an array.

```
tempAttachments:Array[2]
  0:Object
    _id:"12345-678910"
    bytes:412051
    file:File
    size:411532
    title:"someFile.csv"
    headers: Array[3]
        0: optionOne
        1: undefined
        2: optionTwo
        3: undefined
        4: undefined
        5: optionThree
    type:"file"
    fileType:"typeOne"
  1:Object
    _id:"9999-2222"
    bytes:12345
    file:File
    size:23456
    title:"anotherFile.csv"
    headers: Array[3]
        0: optionOne
    type:"file"
    fileType:"typeTwo"
```

There are two elements I am interested in, and that is the _id and headers array.  I am trying to end up with something like this

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
     [id] => 12345-678910
     [optionOne] => 0
     [optionTwo] => 2
     [optionThree] => 5
  )
  [1] => Array
  (
     [id] => 9999-2222
     [optionOne] => 0
  )
)
```

So essentially, the id and the index of the three options as these relate to their column in a file.  The problem is, a file may have a maximum of three options (using the names above) however, they may only have one or two.

So I have started like this

```
const payload = {}

this.tempAttachments.forEach(function (attachment, index) {
  payload[index] = {
    id: attachment._id
  }
})
```

What I am unsure about is how to map the indexes of the options, with the key set as their name, if they exist.  What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) based approach.

Comment: What is `optionOne`, `optionTwo`, ... within the `headers` array? is it a type? can it somehow be handled as string / transformed in to a string for the expected output part?

Comment: They are just strings

Comment: Please post your data in JSON format so that we can easily use it in tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an environment/setting for a classic combined approach of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (here: create a new type from each `attachment` type) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (here: create/collect new option data only for valid `header`/`option` items) ...

```js
const tempAttachments = [{
  _id: "12345-678910",
  bytes: 412051,
  file: "File",
  size: 411532,
  title: "someFile.csv",
  headers: [
    "optionOne",
    undefined,
    "optionTwo",
    undefined,
    undefined,
    "optionThree"
  ],
  type:"file",
  fileType:"typeOne"
}, {
  _id: "9999-2222",
  bytes: 12345,
  file: "File",
  size: 23456,
  title: "anotherFile.csv",
  headers: [
    "optionOne"
  ],
  type: "file",
  fileType: "typeTwo"
}];


function collectValidOptionData(collector, optionItem, idx) {
  // if (optionItem != null) {
  //  collector[String(optionItem)] = idx
  // }
  if (typeof optionItem === 'string') {
    collector[optionItem] = idx;
  }
  return collector;
}

function createOptionTypeFromAttachment(attachmentType) {
  return attachmentType.headers.reduce(collectValidOptionData, {
    id: attachmentType._id
  });
}


console.log(
  'tempAttachments.map(createOptionTypeFromAttachment) : ',
  tempAttachments.map(createOptionTypeFromAttachment)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

A clean way to do this, is using the `Array.map` method, it creates a new array from another.

(More Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

The code below will convert the `tempAttachments` to the new format, where is based in this structure:

```
[
  {
    id: AttachmentID
    optionName: optionIndex
    optionName: optionIndex
    ...
  }
]
```

It will only add options that have a value, ignoring `undefined` options.

Solution:

```
const payload = tempAttachments.map(attachment => {
  const newAttachment = {
    id: attachment._id,
  }

  attachment.headers.forEach((option, index) => {
    if (option) {
      newAttachment[option] = index;
    }
  })

  return newAttachment;
})
```

Comment: I think false and 0.. and other falsy values will not be added.

Comment: Yes, any falsy values will be ignored, that includes 0, false, empty strings, undefined, etc.

I said specifically `undefined` because in this case, only `strings` and `undefined` are in the array.

It's only to facilitate understanding and dosn't overwhelm he with information.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```js
const tempAttachments = [{
    _id: "12345-678910",
    bytes: 412051,
    file: 'File',
    size: 411532,
    title: "someFile.csv",
    headers: [
        'optionOne',
        undefined,
        'optionTwo',
        undefined,
        undefined,
        'optionThree'
    ],
    type: "file",
    fileType: "typeOne"
}, {
    _id: "9999-2222",
    bytes: 12345,
    file: 'File',
    size: 23456,
    title: "anotherFile.csv",
    headers: [
        'optionOne',
        'optionTwo',
        'optionThree'
    ],
    type: "file",
    fileType: "typeTwo",
}];

const output = tempAttachments.reduce((akku, item) => {
    let akkuItem = {
        id: item._id,
    };
    item.headers.forEach((value, index) => {
        if(typeof value !== 'undefined') {
            akkuItem[value] = index;
        }
    });
    akku.push(akkuItem);
    return akku;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: `item.headers` is an array. There is no need to process it with `Object.entries` ... `item.headers.forEach` already will do. On the other hand it was better to make use of `reduce` for structures one does want to collect only certain items from (thus `reduce` instead of `forEach`). Then again `map` instead of `reduce` for the outer structure was the preferable choice for one does want to process/map every `attachment` type.

Comment: You are right, header is not an object.. Have changed the code :)
Thanx.